# How to get documents of a collection having a specific subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

For a Flutter project my Firestore structure looks like this:

```
posts(collection) --> document1
                  --> document2 --> applications(sub-collection)
                  --> document3
                  --> document4 --> applications(sub-collection)
                  --> document5
```

I want to get the documents which have `applications` sub-collection, in this example document2 & document4. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: It'd be better if you share a snapshot of your Firestore firebase to make things easier...Could your please add it?

Comment: Snapshot added.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to run two `get` queries to get both `querysnapshot`(s)

```
db.collection('posts').doc('document2').collection('applications').get()
db.collection('posts').doc('document4').collection('applications').get()
```

Then merge both results into a single `List<QuerySnapshot>` and parse your result as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

As Timothy said in his answer, one option is to perform a separate read for each subcollections, and then merge them in your application code.

Alternatively you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) (Flutter [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html)) to read from all `applications` collections at once. There is no way to limit such a read to just `document2` and `document4` though, so this only works if those are the only `applications` collections in your database.